# How to write all log output to file spring boot

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, logback

I'm using logback-spring.xml in a spring boot project.  I want to log all uncaught exceptions to a file.  Basically just direct the output from the console to a file.  I've tried several variations of logback-spring.xml.

I tried this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="com.mine" level="WARN" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE">
            <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
                <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
            </contextListener>
        </appender-ref>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

with this in my main method `SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();`

I've tried this from the spring docs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

this is in my application.yml

```
logging:
  file: C:\dev\assessment-tool\logs\application.log
  config: classpath:logback-spring.xml
```

For these it will log all the start up logging messages but when an exception is thrown and not caught it goes to the console and doesn't show up in the log file.  How can I make uncaught exceptions go to a log file?

Comment: It should be easier to redirect the standard output to file.

Comment: an exception like your main thread is dying, or an exception from a web endpoint?

Comment: same for me. Micronaut (which is based on spring boot) does not print exceptions neither in file nor in console. Even if I'm explicitly throwing it.

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the levels you're assigning to the loggers in the `logback-spring.xml` file.

According to the logback architecture documentation, (you can check it [here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html)) "The effective level for a given logger L, is equal to the first non-null level in its hierarchy, starting at L itself and proceeding upwards in the hierarchy towards the root logger".

You're assigning level "INFO" on your root logger, and level "WARN" on the logger "com.mine". None of them get "called" when there is an exception, ex: logger.error(Exception e).

One solution is assign the level "DEBUG" or "ERROR" to the logger "com.mine" or to the root logger, because they have attached the appender "FILE".

Comment: Did you change the level of the logger?

Comment: Yes I tried `DEBUG` and `ERROR` on the `com.mine` logger

Comment: The problem not with levels though. Levels are working fine. It's just not printing Exceptions which are not cought